# Concatenation within IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I'm completely stuck on this one -- I need to use IMPORTRANGE function but want to make the sheet it pulls from flexible via concatenation -- here is my formula with a scrubbed URL:

```
=importrange("https://docs.google.com...",("""'"&B5&"'!$F15"&""""))
```

This gives me an error "**Cannot find range or sheet for imported range**"

When I hover over

```
("""'"&B5&"'!$F15"&"""")
```

I receive the correct string:

```
"'Q1 19.08.19'!$F15"
```

Moreover, when I try a hard-coded version of the formula:

```
=importrange("https://docs.google.com/...","'Q1 19.08.19'!$F15")
```

It provides the correct answer, which makes me think this is a structural issue, rather than my code.

Thanks so much for reading!!

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On IMPORTRANGE the apostrophes aren't required. Instead of

```
("""'"&B5&"'!$F15"&"""")
```

use

```
B5&"!$F15"
```

Comment: Can I buy you a beer? Thanks : )